# How many bytes would you need to represent the new Mersenne prime number as an integer?

Tags: math

How many bytes would you need to store `2^57,885,161 - 1` as an integer?

Comment: Wouldn't that be exactly 57'885'161 bits?

Comment: Floor((57,885,161 + 7) / 8) is a pretty close.

Comment: @Mistycial - I'm sorry, I thought int was already a format? I wasn't aware of any other formats...

Comment: There's no fixed integer type that goes up that high. You'd have to store it in some `BigInteger`-like type.

Comment: @pfnuesel - can you explain a bit why would that be?

Comment: @Gregs - can you explain a bit why would that be?

Comment: By format, I mean: Raw binary? Base 10 in ASCII? Base 16 in ASCII? You need to clarify.

Comment: @Mysticial I'm not sure... The way a int is usually stored inside a computer, so I guess raw binary?

Comment: I would store it as `2^57885161-1` which takes only 12 bytes. An expression evaluator can decode the meaning of the what "number"/byte-concatenation is stored.

Comment: @AugustoDiasNoronha A "normal" `int` cannot store a number this big. In raw binary something this big is usually stored as an array of integers in base `2^32` or `2^64`.

Comment: Close Voters: If you're gonna close this, at least choose the right reason. This isn't "Too Localized". If anything, it might be "Off-Topic".

Comment: @Mysticial I don't believe this is "actual, practical problem" he or anyone is ever going to encounter.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I disagree. The people who found it had to represent it. Anybody who needs to do arithmetic on it will encounter it. I'm not saying it's a good question. It's just that "Too Localized" is the wrong close reason.

Comment: @Mysticial At least we agree that it *should* be closed. The close reasons can't possibly cover all types of bad questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming we're doing two's complement and that 8 bits is equal to one byte; we'd need at least (57,885,161+7)/8 bytes.

If you needed a simple way to possibly explain it is by using mathematical induction that says 2^32 - 1 is the maximum number that a 32-bit integer would represent, and 32 is a base of 2 that is divisible by 8, our assumed number of bits per byte. 2^32 - 1 would be 4 bytes.

Extending this definition of assumptions you have the number 2^57885161 which isn't divisible by 8, but adding 7 to it is. So you're left with 2^57885168, and when you divide it by 8 you get the resultant 7235646 bytes.

This is just an explanation of GregS's comment.

Answer (score 3):

The answer strongly depends on what you will do with it. If you are writing a program that exclusively works with Mersenne primes, you'd probably only need four bytes to store it, with the understanding that it represented a Mersenne prime exponent.

If you want to store it as a typical uncompressed "big integer", it will take around 7235646 bytes (ceildiv(57885161, 8)). Some formats are more efficient than others. For example, the Python `long` format uses 7718048 bytes to store this number on my machine (`(2**57885161 - 1).__sizeof__()`) due to format overhead (as Python uses 30-bit digits).

Comment: C'mon, OP didn't specify the format! So I picked a nice compressed format for him.

Comment: Ok, but make it a comment.

Comment: @GregS comments are for non-answering replies. This reply is an answer, so it should ideally be posted as an answer.

Comment: Okay haha. How would you represent it as a "normal" number?

Comment: @GregS: expanded. Better?